# UITextfield shadow

Tags: swift, uikit

I want to add shadow to my `UITextfield` I tried code below, shadows work fine, but there is one thing, it is also set on the text inside my `UITextfield` any solutions ?

```swift
  passwordTextField.layer.masksToBounds = false
  passwordTextField.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
  passwordTextField.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
  passwordTextField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 1.0, height: 1.0)
  passwordTextField.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
```

picture for better understanding:
[image]

as you can see on the picture above, shadow is also set on textfield, how can I only set shadow to corner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just set the textfield background color to white and it will remove the text shadow.

```
passwordTextField.backgroundColor = .white // or whatever color you need
```